# When is `_result_cache` populated in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to step through Django (3.1.2) code in PyCharm to figure out when `_result_cache` is actually populated, but it doesn't seem possible (some critical steps seem to be skipped even if I step into every line of code possible). For example, say, I have a `view` function that does:

```
def my_view(request):
    data = MyModel.objects.all()
    for d in data:
        # do something with every object in the table
```

When I step into this view function, `all()` is called on `BaseManager` as expected, which calls  `get_queryset()` to create a new `QuerySet` instance (i.e., `QuerySet`'s `__init__` is called). Once `__init__` is finished, `data` is now a `QuerySet` instance and its `_result_cache` is already populated with the data in the `MyModel` table. But during `__init__`, it was set to `None`. So what happened after `__init__` is finished? Is some kind of background thread running that I wasn't tracing?

Comment: Which version of Django are you running?

Comment: @BernardoDuarte My bad. I am running Django 3.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

It is populated at `django/db/models/query.py`:

```py
def _fetch_all(self):
    if self._result_cache is None:
        self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
    if self._prefetch_related_lookups and not self._prefetch_done:
        self._prefetch_related_objects()
```

You can find the specific code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.1.2/django/db/models/query.py#L1308).

Comment: Thanks @Bernardo. I did see the code, but I wonder when this function is called during my `all()` example above. I didn't see it being called when I was stepping through the code (nor from inspecting the source code). Maybe you can enlighten me more. Thanks!

Comment: I also saw that `__iter__` and some other magic methods in `QuerySet` would call this function first, so perhaps it was one of those? But usually PyCharm can step into those methods.